# how can i served same location from many location in nginx?

Tags: nginx

my nginx version : 1.17.3

I want served same template from many url my site in nginx

for example-

```
localhost:0000/adprofit
localhost:0000/adprofit/0
localhost:0000/adprofit/0/2
localhost:0000/adprofit/asdlk/asd/asd
localhost:0000/adprofit/sand/12312/asd/?AS?Dsa
```

in any case if i catch same keyword like 'adprofit'.
my site user must be served 'adprofit.html' template.
BUT, NO REWRITE, NO REDIRECT.
i want keep user request url.

My directory:

```
build
|
|-index.html
|-index.js
|-adprofit
|   |
|   |-adprofit.js
|   |-adprofit.html
|
|-another directories...
```

I succeed served from diffrent url used 'alias'.

```
location /all {
     allow all;
     alias ./build/adprofit;
     index adprofit.html;
}
```

in this case keep url `localhost:0000/all/` and view template `adprofit.html`.

and this case too.

Code:

```
location /adprofit/all {
     allow all;
     alias ./build/adprofit;
     index adprofit.html;
}
url : 'localhost:0000/adprofit/all/'
```

my nginx code:

```
server {
     listen       8888;
     server_name  192.168.0.25;
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
     access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

     location / {
      allow all;
      root ./build;
      index  index.html;
      }

 location /adprofit {
  allow all;
  alias ./build/adprofit;
  index adprofit.html;
 }
}
```

my try case:

```
location /adprofit/ {
     allow all;
     alias ./build/adprofit;
     index adprofit.html;
}
succeed url : 'localhost:0000/adprofit/'
failed url : 'localhost:0000/adprofit/[anykeyword]' => 404 error page

code2)
location ~*/adprofit/(all|update|event) {
     allow all;
     alias ./build/adprofit;
     index adprofit.html;
}
succeed url : 'localhost:0000/adprofit/'
failed url : 'localhost:0000/adprofit/all and update and event' => 403 Forbidden
```

how can i resolve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

[`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive is a better approach here. This config will always point to the same files (adprofit.html).

Tested and works:

`/adprofit`

`/adprotif/random`

```
location /adprofit {
    alias /tmp/;
    try_files /adprofit.html =404
}
```